# how to add a non-selectable item to a List in J2ME

Tags: java-me, mobile, j2mepolish

I would like to be able to add a non-selectable element to a list within a j2me screen. At the moment any item that I add to the List can be navigated to on the screen, such that it is selected and is surrounded by a black border.

Is possible to add an element to a List which cannot be selected in this way?

Can this be achieved through some other means or using a different UI object like a Form?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick thoughts. How about to use Form with CustomItem.

Please see this document for CustomItem => http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/customitem/

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me, if you use J2MEPolish. If you do, style your item with the *icon-inactive* css-attribute as described [here](http://www1.j2mepolish.org/docs/gui-item-filteredchoicegroup.html). So for example:

```
.inactiveListItem extends listItem {
    icon-inactive: true;
    border: none;
}
```